# What is using up space in database file?

Tags: sql-server, datafile

I am attempting to empty a database file

Data has been shifted from a database file by using the emptyfile shrink command and then rebuilding/reorganising all heaps and indexes so that the data is pushed to the other files in the filegroup.

The amount of lob data in the file group is approx 1GB, acccording to dm_db_partition_stats and yet according to the SpaceUsed file property, we are still using 40GB of the file that I am trying to empty.

What could be using up all this data?

Comment: Check this one out http://williamweber.net/table-disk-space-usage-by-filegroup-and-partition/

Comment: Have you updated stats and/or running sp_spaceused with option @updateusage = true